# I decided to keep both scenes loaded in the hierarchy since it's easier to reference variables between them. How can I restart then a new game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the Hierarchy I have two scenes when running the game first time. 
The scene that contains all the gameplay objects all the objects are disabled.
The main menu scene objects are enabled.

Now this script is attached to the main menu and the function PlayGame is being called from a Play button On Click event :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool sceneLoaded = false;

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);

        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;
    }

    private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
    {
        sceneLoaded = true;
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

And this script is attached to one active gameobject on the gameplay scene and all it does is to check if I'm in the main menu or not and then to decide if to setactive or not all the gameplay objects :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;

public class ActiveScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameData;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(MainMenu.sceneLoaded == true)
        {
            gameData.SetActive(true);

            MainMenu.sceneLoaded = false;
        }

        if(BackToMainMenu.loadedMainMenuScene == true)
        {
            gameData.SetActive(false);

            BackToMainMenu.loadedMainMenuScene = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the Hierarchy :

You can see that the GameObject name Active Scene in the top scene is enabled gameobject while all the other gameobjects are disabled. On this Active Scene I attached the script ActiveScene.

This way when I click the Play button a new game start and when I hit the escape key it's getting back to the main menu.

The problem is when I hit the escape key and then click the Play button again it will keep load to the Hierarchy the main menu scene over and over again.

[image: Hierarchy]

And this is after few times I hit the escape key and then started a new game over again by clicking the Play button :

[image: While game is running]

This is the script to return to the main menu using the escape key. The script is attached to the Game Manager object in the game scene :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool loadedMainMenuScene = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            loadedMainMenuScene = true;
        }
    }
}
```

- I want to keep both scenes in the Hierarchy all the time since it's easier then to reference between variables in both scenes.
- When both scenes in the Hierarchy it's also easier to restart a new game by re loading the gameplay scene.
- The problem is when restarting a new game I have to set the flag bool sceneLoaded to false but then next time since it's false it will load the main menu scene to the Hierarchy over and over again.

Comment: See, this is why scenes are a problem. Either (a) use them to segment functionality and deal with data transfer properly or (b) don't use multiple scenes at all.

Comment: @Draco18s How about creating a prefab of the Game Data and from the main menu to Instantiate and Destroy it when starting a new game ? Is that logic ?

Comment: **If** you want to go for multiple scenes here is what I would rather do usually: Have a third scene `Main` which is your master scene and never gets unloaded. From this scene you control which other scenes you load e.g. switching forth and back between a Menu Scene and the In-game scene, both loaded **additionally** by the Main scene. Every logic that has to be handled between various scenes is done by the Main scene, it knows which scene(s) is(are) loaded and which references exist (scene objects write references to a component in the main scene onload)